# Can't install Windows 7 from USB (GRUB)

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, grub

After 7 years of using windows 7 i decided to reinstall because it slowed down considerably. Used Rufus to create a USB using the ISO that i used to install it in 2013. But now when i try to boot through the USB i get the following screen:

[image]

Why is that?

Additional info:
I have Xubuntu in another partition in the same drive (Installed this year). GRUB 2 as the bootloader. Maybe that's the issue?
ASUS motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with the image on USB.
Please make sure you are using newest version of Rufus, however I found it not very reliable so I moved on to Etcher recently:
[Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/)

Xubuntu shouldn't be an issue, however the GRUB would be most likely overwritten, so after installing windows, you would need to start Xubuntu from recovery media to re-install GRUB. otherwise you will no longer be able to start Xubuntu. You would also need to update GRUB with the information where it should look for windows.

Windows 7 is no longer supported, do you know that you can still upgrade it to windows 10 for free?

Comment: Etcher corrupted my flash drive so i don't use it. Also i don't like windows 10 and will use 7 until Microsoft comes up with something good like 7 again.

Comment: @Gyugas what I suspect is that the flash drive was already failing, hence the failure to start windows installer properly

Comment: nope the flash drive works when transferring files. Etcher made it unrecognizable by windows so i had to do some console procedures to restore it.

Comment: @Gyugas did you try to use rufus to create bootable image on another flash drive?

Comment: Yes the problem was with the flash drive. Thanks.

Comment: Gyugas, can you please try @Akeo 's advice and let us know how it works, hopefully accepting one of the solutions as the right one?

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling that you have two issues:

1. Your display cannot handle basic graphics modes.
2. You created a UEFI targeted bootable drive in Rufus instead of creating a BIOS/Legacy one.

No idea how you can ago around fixing the first issue, but for the second one, you may want to read [this](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Help_I_created_a_Windows_installation_drive_but_it_doesnt_boot) and recreate your USB in Rufus after making sure Target system is set to BIOS or UEFI-CSM.

Incidentally, I'm pretty sure that, if your monitor could show it, it would display a message that tells you that you are trying to boot a UEFI-only bootable drive in BIOS/Legacy mode, and that you need to recreate it to target BIOS/Legacy in Rufus so that it works.